# Does Square Accept Android Pay in the SqPaymentForm?

Tags: javascript, android-pay, square

I have a web app. In this web app I'm accepting payments via Square. I want to support both Apple Pay and Android Pay. I noticed that the `SqPaymentForm` supports Apple Pay. However, I did not see anything related to Android Pay.

Is there a way to use Android Pay for online payments with Square?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android Pay isn’t currently available for Square’s API. This is a very popular feature request and we hope to have more options for you soon.

We don’t have any public roadmaps for our upcoming features, but I’ll be sure to share your thoughts with the rest of the API team.